# jQuery.browser or jQuery.support?

Tags: jquery

Here's the problem. IE doesn't render a scrollable tbody in a table element right as far as I've tested (definitely not in IE8). Firefox does, and I've heard of most others. So I found a jquery plugin to make it scrollable.

So I figured, hey if IE is the only one that's not doing it, why not just call the jquery plugin only on IE. So a little googling (I'm new to jquery) and I see you can call

`$.browser.msie` tells me if it's IE

but on the jquery website it says to try and use jquery.support object.

Well what feature is this called?

And is it better to use jquery.support or $.browser ?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9 there is no more `$.browser`. 
read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8890460/104380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should extend jquery.support to have something like scrollableTbody. This way, your code shows clearly what you are testing and you can later adapt the code at the right place when new/other browsers show different behavior.

Comment: if I extend then I would have to have a separate file that does the checks? any tutorial on this? not really a javascript guy