# IF condition to enable a script property (jquery) for IE7 users?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To condition something in jquery for IE7, [I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755459/how-to-detect-ie7-and-lower-using-jquery-support) it's best to use this in the `<HEAD>`:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
```

Now, out of the following code,

I want `transition: "elastic",` to be there only if it's ie7:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cbox").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.colorbox({
            transition: "elastic",
            overlayClose: false,
            opacity: 0.8,
        });
        return false
    })
});
```

So I tried doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cbox").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.colorbox({
            if ($('html').hasClass('ie7') {transition: "elastic",}
            overlayClose: false,
            opacity: 0.8,
        });
        return false
    })
});
```

But it's not the way to do this I guess... how should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to dynamically set the transition

```
transition: $("html").hasClass("ie7") ? "elastic":"none",
```

Note according to the documentation the default value is `elastic` so really you do not need to set a transition at all, unless you want non-ie7 browsers to have some other transition type.

Comment: +1, I forgot about ternary :)  one note of caution though - it assumes `""` is the default value, rather than it not being specified at all

Comment: Yea wasnt sure of what the actual default value for transition was so just left it blank, edited it to be `none`

Comment: Thanks! this is working good as well. the elastic was just a quick example :)

Answer (score 2):

If the `html` element definitely has that class on it, the proper way to structure your options for the `colorbox` would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cbox").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var opt = {
            overlayClose: false,
            opacity: 0.8
        };
        if ($('html').hasClass('ie7'))        
            opt.transition = 'elastic';
        $.colorbox(opt);
        return false
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm seeing a syntax error with Dreamweaver, maybe something is missing?

Comment: sorry, had missed a bracket. Fixed it (and added a missing semicolon that most browsers would ignore)

Answer (score 0):

Very straight forward answer to this, just read carefully this link : [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

jQuery.browser property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin.

The best practice when you do have jQuery 1.9 or earlier version is that you should use this approach for specific browser detection.

Comment: Note that [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) was deprecated and then removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: @James Thorpe: Agreed! but this feature is available through the jQuery.migrate plugin.