# How to simply detect browser type with JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using JavaScripts `lastIndexOf()` which doesnt work in IE so I must write an alternative code.

I simply want an if statement to do something like:

```
if(IE = true){
  //run alternative to lastIndexOf()
}
```

But I am really struggling with finding a way to achieve this.

So far I have tried the following:

JQuery's `.browser` is deprecated.

`.support` seems to only detect certain facets or features of a
   browser.

Modifying `.support` with JavaScript, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890460/how-to-detect-ie7-and-ie8-using-jquery-support), wont work and
   throws errors.

The `hasClass()` method no longer works:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
if ($('html').hasClass('ie7');
```

Would anyone know a simple way to just detect the browser type?

Comment: I can't find any jQuery documentation for `lastIndexOf`. Did you perhaps mean [`String.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) or [`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

Comment: @Phil sorry, I thinks its just a JavaScript thing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: The best way to fix your issue is given by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf#Compatibility).

---

[How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser/) has a very nice way of getting the browser type and version as a string.

You might also find [Detect IE version (prior to v9) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript) helpful for IE-specific detection.

You can also try:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0 )
```

I have not tested this however.

Comment: I'm looking for the source, can't find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791/80860

Comment: Thanks, found it myself too.

Comment: `You might also find Detect IE version in Javascript helpful.` is exactly what I needed. Added the piece of code I used to your answer above

Comment: -1 Browser detection is a flawed strategy and has been considered a very bad idea for a long time. Please don't suggest it, paticularly when there is a very simple way to detect support for `indexOf` and deal with cases where it's lacking.

Comment: I assumed that the asker wanted to detect browser type. I agree however that browser detection is not the best choice for this application. Not sure but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers might be more helpful in that direction.

Answer (score 4):

There are cases when you have no choice but to use browser detection, but in this case it is better if you detect the function itself, and [shim it in if it is not there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc).

Comment: I always check MDN for shims / polyfills under the [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf#Compatibility) sections

Comment: @Phil: very good point.

Comment: Yeah do not browser sniff, feature detect. FWIW IE supports lastIndexOf, here is a copy from my console doing a quick example.

Comment: JavaScript Console is attached and accepting commands.
   var str = "Hello planet earth, you are a great planet.";
 var n = str.lastIndexOf("planet");
   undefined
   n
   36